# Modify the value of a property during PropertyChangedEventHandler

Tags: c#, class, inotifypropertychanged

I am writing an application that reads information on the form and transforms that data in various ways based on a set of rules. Rather than get into the why's of the scenario, I will just lay out a basic example of what I am trying to do. Please note, this whole business of using PropertyChangedEventHandler and INotifyPropertyChanged is very new to me and I am still reading and learning about it.

Here is a *sample* class I use to capture the first name and a message to the user:

```
class Names : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _firstName;
    public string firstName { get { return _firstName; } set { SetField(ref _firstName, value, "firstName"); } }

    private string _nameMessage;
    public string nameMessage { get { return _nameMessage; } set { SetField(ref _nameMessage, value, "nameMessage"); } }

    #region handle property changes
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        //if the value did not change, do nothing.
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        //the value did change, so make the modification.
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Whenever the property for *firstName* changes, I want to automatically modify the value in the *nameMessage* property.

> For example, the user types *John*, so the *nameMessage* property is set
>   to **Hello John**.

This is a very simple example of what I am trying to accomplish but I am getting stuck because it is hard for me to understand how to get the pointer to that particular property for that index.

Here are my two questions:
1) What code should I write to get the changed value and modify it?
2) Does that business logic belong within the class, or should it be in a different class altogether?

Any pointers you can provide would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to cascade a property fro one to another, you could implement your firstName property to be implemented like this:

```
public string firstName 
{  
    get { return _firstName; } 
    set 
    { 
       if (SetField(ref _firstName, value))
       {
            // first name changed, so update the other field too
            this.nameMessage = string.Format("hello {0}", _firstName);
       }
    } 
}
```

you could also do this without every actually storing the nameMessage as a field.  it could be generated on the fly:

```
public string nameMessage { get { return string.Format("hello {0}", _firstName); } }
```

and simply add an additional property change notification to the setter for first name:

```
    set 
    { 
       if (SetField(ref _firstName, value))
       {
            // first name changed, so update the other field too
            NotifyPropertyChanged("nameMessage");
       }
    }
```

related: one trick is using the `CallerMemberName` annotation to provide a default value for the property name, so you don't have to pass that in your `setfield` calls

```
 protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The only problem I am having is slightly unrelated but is part of your answer. The [CallMemberName] tip you gave does not work as VS/C# does not recognize it. I am using .Net 4.6.1.

Comment: typo.  `[CallerMemberName]`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Perhaps it would be best to ask the question again, showing more details of the code just in case there is something else I am doing that is causing the problem?

Comment: define "this did not work".  what didn't happen?  you can find exactly this same kind of example of using notify property change all over the place.  I use it every day.  is `SetField` incorrectly returning false (nothing changed?)  is your `NotifyPropertyChanged` implementation working?  is anyone subscribed to property change notifications? use a debugger and step through.

Comment: by "this did not work", I meant CallMemberName was not recognized by Visual Studio and caused a compile error. I will read your points and take a closer look.

Comment: because you are mispelling it.  `CallerMemberName`.  **Caller**, not Call.  as long as you are on .net4.5 or newer, it is available.  you might need to add a using for it, but it is there.

Comment: Yup, my bad. I did not properly type it in my response. This is what I have: **protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string[CallerMemberName] propertyName = null)**. When I type this, CallerMemberName does not display as a type-ahead option and it gives me the error "Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration."

Comment: another typo.  the annotation has to go before the type `[CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null`.  will fix the example